# SharePoint2k7: Custom List EditForm annoying field labels, how to remove?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, customization

I experienced some 'strange' differences on SharePoint 2007 between my TST and PRD environment. I was working on customising a list's EditForm, and I noticed the new form I created on TST displayed correctly like this:
[image: Correct display format]

This is the style I wanted. However, when I performed exactly same operation on the PRD, this was what I got, note the extra form field labels and wrappers around the same two fields:
[image: Incorrect display format with extra field container and field label]

The source (of the generated html files) were different too:

```
    Correctly displayed:

<tr><td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel"><H3 class="ms-standardheader"><nobr>Profit Centre<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span></nobr></H3></td>
<td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody"><span dir="none">
        <input name="ctl00$m$g_193d5406_ba72_454b_b14c_87873ba714d6$ff5_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField" type="text" value="ALL" maxlength="255" id="ctl00_m_g_193d5406_ba72_454b_b14c_87873ba714d6_ff5_1_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" title="Profit Centre" class="ms-long" /><br>
    </span></td></tr>
<tr><td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel"><H3 class="ms-standardheader"><nobr>Status<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span></nobr></H3></td>
<td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody"><span dir="none"><select name="ctl00$m$g_193d5406_ba72_454b_b14c_87873ba714d6$ff6_1$ctl00$DropDownChoice" id="ctl00_m_g_193d5406_ba72_454b_b14c_87873ba714d6_ff6_1_ctl00_DropDownChoice" title="Status" class="ms-RadioText">
                    <option selected="selected" value="Not Yet Reconciled">Not Yet Reconciled</option>
                    <option value="Reconciled">Reconciled</option>
                    <option value="Reviewed">Reviewed</option>
                    <option value="Rejected by Reviewer">Rejected by Reviewer</option>
                    <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
                    <option value="Rejected by Approver">Rejected by Approver</option>

                </select><br></span></td></tr>


===========================================================
Annoying wrapper displayed:

<tr><td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel"><H3 class="ms-standardheader"><nobr>Profit Centre<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span></nobr></H3></td>
<td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
<div align="left" class="ms-formfieldcontainer">
<div class="ms-formfieldlabelcontainer" nowrap="nowrap">
<span class="ms-formfieldlabel" nowrap="nowrap">Profit Centre</span></div>
<div class="ms-formfieldvaluecontainer">
<span dir="none">
        <input name="ctl00$m$g_7716bb24_9fc9_4e72_a2c6_bec888418014$ff6_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField" type="text" value="ALL" maxlength="255" id="ctl00_m_g_7716bb24_9fc9_4e72_a2c6_bec888418014_ff6_1_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" title="Profit Centre" class="ms-long" /><br>
    </span></div></div></td></tr>
<tr><td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel"><H3 class="ms-standardheader"><nobr>Status<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span></nobr></H3></td>
<td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
<div align="left" class="ms-formfieldcontainer">
<div class="ms-formfieldlabelcontainer" nowrap="nowrap">
<span class="ms-formfieldlabel" nowrap="nowrap">Status</span></div><div class="ms-formfieldvaluecontainer">
<span dir="none">
<select name="ctl00$m$g_7716bb24_9fc9_4e72_a2c6_bec888418014$ff7_1$ctl00$DropDownChoice" id="ctl00_m_g_7716bb24_9fc9_4e72_a2c6_bec888418014_ff7_1_ctl00_DropDownChoice" title="Status" class="ms-RadioText">
                    <option value="Not Yet Reconciled">Not Yet Reconciled</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="Reconciled">Reconciled</option>
                    <option value="Reviewed">Reviewed</option>
                    <option value="Rejected by Reviewer">Rejected by Reviewer</option>
                    <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
                    <option value="Rejected by Approver">Rejected by Approver</option>
                </select><br></span></div></div></td></tr>
```

How do I remove the extra field containers and related field labels? Why did it behave differently on these two SP2007 environments?

Your tips and answers are much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the two environment were of different flavours. The TST environment was running SharePoint Content Management Server with Microsoft.SharePoint.dll version = 12.0.6421.1000. While as the PRD environment was an Enterprise edtion with Microsoft.SharePoint.dll version = 12.0.6565.5001.

And thanks Mirjam for this excellent solution:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/sharepointcustomization/thread/f00d37d3-2254-44fa-8f4d-ae7683c645cf

The workaround is to inject a piece of CSS style sheet to override these two OOB classes:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-formfieldlabelcontainer {
    display: none;
}
.ms-formfieldvaluecontainer {
    border: 0px;
    border-style:hidden;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
</style>
```

And everything looks great now!